# Android Studio can't reference from an object

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This might be a noob post but i think i misclick something and i can't reference an object. Please help

> I am trying to get a reference to `str` but it only shows encapsulation.
>   [image]

Comment: You need to reference in any of the Activity callbacks! Like for eg: `onCreate`, `onStart` etc

Comment: @Sanoop I know, I am just stating an example that i cant reference an object even if the class is not having a parent.

Comment: You can't do that, ok, why are you trying to call the object here?

Comment: @Sanoop As i stated i was only trying to show an example, I changed the  photo with a class that's not extending any parent.

Comment: I totally understand that, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Looks like you are not inside a method at the point where you are editing. Putting `theRef` here would be syntactically incorrect and is therefore not offered by AS.

Comment: No you guys clearly misunderstood, This class right above that screenshot is just a normal class not extending any parent etc `AppCompatActivity` when i try to type a reference to an object. it only shows an encapsulation not the **OBJECT**.

Comment: It does not matter if the class extends something or not. The point is, you must be in a method.

Comment: You can reference the object with in a member function. @HUSTLE, Henry's comment wins

Comment: Please take a look at another screenshot example. I swear something is wrong about my Android Studio

Comment: This example clearly shows that you are on class level, not method level (otherwise the `private` would be illegal). So again: **you are not in a method**. What would you like to put here that starts with a field reference?

Comment: If somebody would try to teamviewer they would understand what is going on.

Comment: Your team viewer details?

Comment: @HUSTLE **YOU CAN NOT WRITE CODE OUTSIDE OF METHOD!** You can only declare fields, classes, methods. Encapsulation has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Hope you understand what i just did? @HUSTLE

Answer (score 2):

You did not do anything. Nothing wrong here. You are just outside of any method. If you are not inside of any methods, you can only declare variables, methods and initialize in the same line if you want.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of a variable defines the section of the code in which the variable is visible. As a general rule, variables that are defined within a block are not accessible outside that block. **Which can only be accessed inside a member function with the class, or the object referencing to the class**

What you are trying to do is create an object as header variable, whose visibility is with the class's member functions, or any object referencing to the class.

Simple as this, you cannot reference like this
And there is nothing wrong with android studio, This is what Java is

[image]